# Cuda 5.0 Linking Issue

Tags: cuda, linker-errors

I'm just trying to build an old project of mine using cuda 5.0 preview.
I get an Error when linking, telling me that certain cuda functions can not be found. For example:

`undefined reference to 'cudaMalloc'`.

My linking command includes the following options for cuda :

> -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/home/myhome/NVIDIA_CUDA_Samples/C/lib -L/home/myhome/NVIDIA_CUDA_Samples/C/common/lib/linux -lcudart

`ls -lah /usr/local/cuda/lib64/` gives me 8 cuda libraries including libcudart.so.5.0.7 with symlinks using only the .so-file-ending.

`ls /home/myhome/NVIDIA_CUDA_Samples/C/lib/` gives me an empty directory, which is kind of strange?

`ls /home/myhome/NVIDIA_CUDA_Samples/C/common/lib/linux/` gives me two directories: i686 and x86_64 both containing only libGLEW.a

I have no idea which way to look for a solution. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is my complete linking command (TARGET_APPLICATION is my binary and x86_64/Objectfiles.o stands for all (23) object files including the object file compiled with nvcc):

`/home/myhome/nullmpi-0.7/bin/mpicxx -CC=g++ -I. -I/home/myhome/nullmpi-0.7/src  -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/home/myhome/NVIDIA_CUDA_Samples/C/lib -L/home/myhome/NVIDIA_CUDA_Samples/C/common/lib/linux -lcudart   -o TARGET_APPLICATION x86_64/Objectfiles.o /usr/lib/liblapack.so /usr/lib/libblas.so /home/myhome/nullmpi-0.7/lib/libnullpmpi.a -lm`

I use [nullmpi](http://wissrech.ins.uni-bonn.de/research/projects/nullmpi/) for compilation and linking (project uses MPI and CUDA), which internally uses `g++` as can be seen by `-CC=g++`, i wanted to keep this stuff out.

The compilation command for my cuda object file:

`/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -c -arch=sm_21 -L/home/myhome/NVIDIA_CUDA_Samples/C/lib -O3  kernelwrapper.cu -o x86_64/kernelwrapper.RELEASE.2.o`

`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` results in:

> `/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib:`

`echo $PATH` results in:

> otherOptions`:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/home/myhome/nullmpi-0.7/bin`

I'm building 64-bit. For the sake of completeness I'm building on Ubuntu 12.04. (64bit).
**Building the CUDA Samples works fine.**

**SOLUTION** (thanks to talonmies for pointing me to it):

This is the correct linking command:

`/home/myhome/nullmpi-0.7/bin/mpicxx -CC=g++ -I. -I/home/myhome/nullmpi-0.7/src  -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/home/myhome/NVIDIA_CUDA_Samples/C/lib -L/home/myhome/NVIDIA_CUDA_Samples/C/common/lib/linux  -o TARGET_APPLICATION x86_64/Objectfiles.o /usr/lib/liblapack.so /usr/lib/libblas.so /home/myhome/nullmpi-0.7/lib/libnullpmpi.a -lcudart -lm`

Comment: Please provide your complete command line and whether you are compiling 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: This is strange. I usually never have to link to anything for standard CUDA programs. Did you remember to modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: I don't see any source files or objects in your compile line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your linking statements in the incorrect order. It should be something more like this:

```
/home/myhome/nullmpi-0.7/bin/mpicxx -CC=g++ -I. -I/home/myhome/nullmpi-0.7/src \
    -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64  \
    -L/home/myhome/NVIDIA_CUDA_Samples/C/lib \ 
    -L/home/myhome/NVIDIA_CUDA_Samples/C/common/lib/linux \ 
    -o TARGET_APPLICATION x86_64/Objectfiles.o \
     /home/myhome/nullmpi-0.7/lib/libnullpmpi.a -llapack -lblas -lm -lcudart
```

The source of your problem is that you have specified the CUDA runtime library *before* the object file that contains a dependency to it. The linker simply discards `libcudart.so` from the linkage because there are no dependencies to it at the point when it is processed. Golden rule in POSIX style compilation statements: linkage statements are parsed left-to-right; so objects containing external dependencies first, libraries satisfying those dependencies afterwards.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help! I should take a look at POSIX rules, until now I was lucky getting my things builded. Strange thing: I used the exactly same Makefiles on Ubuntu 11.10 and Cuda 4.1 and had no problems.